# Send a mail to Admin with a BO link to specific customer in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop 1.6, from a FrontController, I have to send a mail to the administrator of the Shop.

This part works well but I got problems to include a link to the administration page of a specific customer.

The only thing I miss is the name of the administration directory. I would be able to parse and concatenate the `PS_ADMIN_DIR` constant but it is not available from the FrontController.

I'm kinda stuck here.

Here is the code :

```
$admin_customer_link = 
    _PS_BASE_URL_
    .__PS_BASE_URI__
    /* Missing the Administration directory name here */
    .$this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminCustomers', false)
    ."&id_customer=".(int)$customer->id."&viewcustomer";
```

The output I got :

> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/prestashop/index.php?controller=AdminCustomers&id_customer=2&viewcustomer
> ```

The output I need :

> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/prestashop/administration/index.php?controller=AdminCustomers&id_customer=2&viewcustomer
> ```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the use of the administration directory name from the Front End and sending a link to the administration in e-mail is not a good idea for security purpose, I choose to implement this another way.

Instead of send the administration customer's page link to the webmaster by e-mail, I create a new customer Thread and message. After that, I send an e-mail to the customer service. So, when they log in the Back Office, they see a new notification who leads them to the specific user.

[image]

Here is the code :

**ModuleFrontController**

```
// Create a new Customer Thread
$ct = new CustomerThread();
if (isset($customer->id)) {
     $ct->id_customer = (int)$customer->id;
}
$ct->id_shop = (int)$this->context->shop->id;
$ct->id_contact = $contact->id;
$ct->id_lang = (int)$this->context->language->id;
$ct->email = $customer->email;
$ct->status = 'open';
$ct->token = Tools::passwdGen(12);
$ct->add();

// Add a new message to the Customer Thread
if ($ct->id) {
    $cm = new CustomerMessage();
    $cm->id_customer_thread = $ct->id;
    $cm->message = $message;
    $cm->ip_address = (int)ip2long(Tools::getRemoteAddr());
    $cm->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $cm->add();
}
```

Hope it helps someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (standard) way to know the administration folder from a front controller, otherwise all the security will flushed down the toilet :).

What you can do is to retrieve the administration folder from the module 'configuration' or when you install it, and save it somewhere, at the moment I suggest into the database but maybe there is a more safely mode.

Something like:

```
public function install()
{
    // your stuff
    $current_dir = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // this give you the current dir (administration folder included)
    $administration_folder = /* Clean your string with a string replace or preg */
    Configuration::updateValue('PS_MYMOD_ADMIN_DIR', $administration_folder);
    return true;
}
```

Then in your front controller retrieve it by:

```
$adminfolder = Configuration::get('PS_MYMOD_ADMIN_DIR');
```

However I hope you know that you're creating a security breach through e-mail...

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. So, it's not a secure way to do this ?

Comment: I just test it and it's ok. It works but the security token is not valid. Certainly because there is no employee set in the frontController so the token can't be generated correctly.

Comment: I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Yep... Mmm... You can create a custom page in your module, like `customer.php` and redirect the administrator to the admincustomer controller... See the `ajax.php` in the administration folder, maybe helps you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I used another work-around. I create a new customer thread and send an e-mail to the customer service. With this, when connect to the BO, the employee has the new customer message notification and can access the customer configuration page from it. It's secure and more elegant. Thanks anyway for your interest and your advice. I'll post my solution tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, it's a very better solution ;)